# Cannot cast from const std::string to void*

Tags: casting, void-pointers, stdstring

I have a vector of string and Integers something like 
std::vector strvect 
std::vector intvect
when i am casting from these types to void * , casting from string fails where as to the integer it goes through. Any reason?

```cpp
void *data; 
data = (void *)(strvect .front()); 
// gives me the error "Cannot cast from string to void * " 
data = (void *)(intvect.front());
```

Any specific reason?

Answer (score 1):

A non-pointer value can't be converted to a `void` pointer. So either you have to use the address-of operator

```
data = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&strvect.front());
```

or you get the actual C-string pointer

```
data = reinterpret_cast<void*>(strvect.front().c_str());
```

Comment: The correction can be provided even without reinterpret cast something like data = (void *)(&(strvect .front())); But what i am interested to know is if casting differes between UDT and basic data types when done with void *

Comment: @user1122891 Yes it works, as any pointer can be cast implicitly to a void pointer. However, I would rather have an explicit cast to improve both my own understanding of the code in the future (when I've forgotten all about it) and that of others.

Comment: OK. but reinterpret_cast i am told has problems and not safe

Comment: @user1122891 It's not "safe" because it can be used to cast unrelated types to each other, which can lead to strange behaviors.